# Internalization in Dspace

Tags: dspace

In dspace6.0,

Using Internalization , we are able to implement 18 different languages Like 
 Deutsch ( German Language ),etc .

I just wanted to know whether we could implement any other language other than these 18 languages, If so, there is any procedure that must be followed to implement in our preferred language like Regional languages.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

For example, if you wanted to add Catalan language (ca), you should do the following depending on the UI: JSPUI or XMLUI.

### JSPUI

1. Add the new locale to the option `webui.supported.locales` in your `local.cfg`:

   webui.supported.locales = en, de, ca
2. Place the file `Messages_ca.properties` into the directory `[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/jspui/src/main/resources/`.
3. Rebuild and redeploy DSpace.

The translation file should have one of these formats (see [ResourceBundle.getBundle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader))):

- Messages_language_script_country_variant.properties
- Messages_language_script_country.properties
- Messages_language_script.properties
- Messages_language_country_variant.properties
- Messages_language_country.properties
- Messages_language.properties

See [JSPUI specific localization](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/Localization+L10n#LocalizationL10n-JSPUIspecificlocalization) documentation for more information.

### XMLUI

1. Add the new locale to the option `webui.supported.locales` in your `local.cfg`:

   webui.supported.locales = en, de, ca
2. Place the file `messages_ca.xml` into the directory `[dspace-source]/dspace/modules/xmlui/src/main/webapp/i18n/`.
3. Rebuild and redeploy DSpace.

The translation file should have one of these formats:

- messages_language_country_variant.xml
- messages_language_country.xml
- messages_language.xml
- messages.xml

When the user access a page, the files are checked in this order, based upon the locale set up in their browser.

See [XMLUI Configuration and Customization - Multilingual Support](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC6x/XMLUI+Configuration+and+Customization#XMLUIConfigurationandCustomization-MultilingualSupport) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the above reply. I am trying to do it in JSPUI. Also I want to do it in  language which is not dspace i18N language .Example like Hindi which is an Indian language ,but not a  i18N language.

Comment: Thanks for the above reply. I am trying to do it in JSPUI. Also I want to do it in  language which is not dspace I18N language .Example like Hindi which is an Indian language ,but not a  I18N language. I tried it with Hindi but when I switch to Hindi , those Hindi letters are not rendering properly as shown below                                                                à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤µà¤¿à¤­à¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¨ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤µà¤¿à¤­à¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¨ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤µà¤¿à¤­à¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¨ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤ à¤µà¤¿à¤­à¤¿à¤¨à¥à¤¨ à¤à¥ à¤²à¤¿à¤

Comment: I've added the instructions for JSPUI. In your case you should name the files with 'hi' suffix. For example Messages_hi.properties. As to the letters not rendering properly, it looks like an encoding problem. You should check your server, database, browser, etc. are properly set up with UTF-8 locale. Review the DSpace installation documentation and ensure all steps mentioning UTF-8 have been done properly.